# Find summation of multiple 4 in C++

Tags: c++

I have homework to design a form.
I had problem with the sum. I dont know what they mean.

When the “Sum” button is clicked, the summation of all multiples of 4 greater 
than 100 and less than 200 will be found and the result will be displayed in the result 
edit box.

My answer is like this:

```
if(num>100)||(num<200)

  sum=sum+num
```

Comment: Which language? I'm presuming C++ as per the title?

Comment: You added the tags `C#`, `C++` and `C`. These three are radically difference languages - please clear up your question and tags.

Comment: You can calculate the number analytically and return that.

Comment: Do you have to calculate the sum of every multiple of 4 between 100 and 200, or does the user provide numbers and you need to sum up only those numbers provided by the user that are multiples of 4 between 100 and 200?

Comment: Since the beans have been spilled below, I bet you'd get bonus points for implementing a flexible Gauss summation formula correctly (explained [here](http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/) for example).

Answer (score 7):

From what I can gather, it's asking you to "find" all numbers that are divisible by 4, that are between 100 and 200, and then sum them together. I'll provide the pseudo code, but as it's homework, you'll need to figure this one out on your own. :)

```
// Create an array of integers
// Loop from 100 to 200
//     If current index is divisible by 4
//         Add to array
// Sum the array of integers
```

To help you get started with the code, you'll want to use the `for` loop, e.g.

```
for (var index = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // do something 10 times
}
```

and you'll also want to use the [Mod operand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) to determine if the current number if divisible by 4. e.g.

```
if (number % 2 == 0)
{
    // number is even
}
else
{
    // number is odd
}
```

**Alternative approach**

As suggested by @benhoyt, you could increment your loop index by 4 each time, that way you wouldn't need to `x % y` on each iteration, and your number of overall loop executions would go down. Here's the pseudo code:

```
// Create an array of integers
// Set index to 100
// (This loop determines where we should start)
// Whilst index is not divisible by 4, and index is less than 200
//     Add 1 to index
// Whilst index is less than 200
//     Add index to array
//     Add 4 to index
// Sum the array of integers
```

Although this approach requires 2 loops, the number of overall loop executions will be reduced. Within the 2nd loop we're adding 4 to the index, thus we won't need to check if `x % y` is true. Our 2nd loop, instead of being a `for` loop, will now look like this:

```
// 2nd loop
while (index < 200)
{
    // add index to array
    index += 4
}
```

Comment: Yes, good approach. However, note that it's much simpler (and 4x as fast) to just loop from 100 (which is divisible by 4) and skip 4 each time, summing as you go.

Comment: @benhoyt I like your alternative approach. I've updated my post!

Answer (score -2):

//I need to make a restitution to the out-of-context answer I gave earler.

```
int i = 100, sum = 0;
while (i <200)
{
   i = i +4;
   if ( i % 4 == 0)
   {
      sum += i;
   }
}
```

Comment: `i=i +4; if ( i % 4 == 0)`
I guess you want to make **really** sure? Also, might not want to spoon-feed when you see a homework tag.

Comment: I would consider revising your implementation; what would happen for example if they wanted to find the sum of all numbers divisible by 4, that are between 95 and 195? What would happen if we updated `i` to be 95? What would the sum be?